# Angular 4 validator to check 2 controls at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have a reactive form with 2 controls (port_start and port_end) that have the following requirements:

- Both must have a value
- Their values must be between 0 and 65535
- port_start value must be less than port_end value

This is what I tried so far:

```
[...]
this.formModel.addControl('port_start', 
  new FormControl(object.port_start ? object.port_start : 0, 
  [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(65535), this.minMaxValidator('port_start', 'port_end').bind(this)]));

this.formModel.addControl('port_end', 
  new FormControl(object.ort_end ? object.port_end : 0, 
  [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(65535), this.minMaxValidator('port_start', 'port_end').bind(this)]));
[...]
```

This is the custom validator function:

```
minMaxValidator = function(startControl : string, endControl : string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
    let valid = true;
    let valStart = 0;
    let valEnd = 0;

    if(this.formModel.controls[startControl] && this.formModel.controls[endControl]) {
      valStart = <number>this.formModel.controls[startControl].value;

      valEnd = <number>this.formModel.controls[endControl].value;
    }

    valid = valEnd >= valStart;

    return valid ? null : { minmax : true };
  };
}
```

This works fine except for this problem:

- Let's say I type '2' in the 'port_start' field. Angular marks it as non valid because it's more than the value of 'port_end' (which is 0 by default). If I type '5' in the 'port_end' field, the app still shows 'port_start' as invalid, although now it's correct.

I understand that the problem is that I need to re-check the associated field each time I change the other one's value, but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `min`, `max` and `required` validators can be kept as is. If you want to validate one control based on the value of another, you need to lift the validation to the parent control.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorFn, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

const portStartEnd: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
   const start = fg.get('portStart').value;
   const end = fg.get('portEnd').value;

   return start && end && start < end ? null : { startEnd: true };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <input [formControl]="form.get('portStart')" type="number" >
   <input [formControl]="form.get('portEnd')" type="number" >

   {{ form.valid }}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      portStart: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(65535)]],
      portEnd: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(65535)]]
    }, { validator: portStartEnd } );
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gupqvu)

Comment: Still +1 for the solution, although it's possible to keep the validation at control level.

Comment: Well, of course you can do it the other way, but I think this is way simpler to reason about. It is a cross validation after all, so why would you keep this validation at the individual control level?

Comment: I totally agree. That's why I didn't say that you **should**, but only that you **could**.

Comment: Ah, alright :) Have an upvote for creative thinking ^^

Comment: Not really creative, that's what he asked (change listener). Let's say the OP learnt 2 mechanisms in one question !

Answer (score 10):

Unlike @Tomasz said, you can keep the validation at control level.

The secret : listen to changes on your form, and when it occurs, set the validators with the current values.

**[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lz5msy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)** that shows you how it works.

And here is the code I used :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="number" formControlName="start">
  <input type="number" formControlName="end">
</form>

<div *ngIf="form.get('start').hasError('lessThan')">Min should be less than max</div>
<div *ngIf="form.get('end').hasError('moreThan')">Max should be less than min</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      start: [0],
      end: [65535]
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
      this.form.get('start').setValidators(LessThanEnd(+this.form.value.end));
      this.form.get('end').setValidators(MoreThanStart(+this.form.value.start));
    });

  }
}

export function LessThanEnd(end: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    return control.value > end ? { 'lessThan': true } : null;
  };
}

export function MoreThanStart(end: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    return control.value < end ? { 'moreThan': true } : null;
  };
}
```

Comment: (Although I answered your question, this is just informational for the change listener. If you want to implement a working solution, chose @Tomasz)

Comment: Thanks for your help, although both answers work (I did a couple of tests) I decided to use your approach because it was easier to adapt to  my code.

Comment: @Fel it being easier doesn't mean it's the best solution, or even a good practice ! This might sound weird, but could you please mark the other answer as the valid one, for future users that have the same issue as you ?

Comment: No problem. I marked your answer because it was what I used in my app, but I can select the other one as the solution because I tried it and it also works fine.

Comment: I've got a problem related to this, as I am trying to use this solution in two mat-selects. The problem is that both inputs are not validated and updated at the same time, instead one has to manually change both values for it to work.
You can see what I mean in your stackblitz demo; if you change the values by clicking the arrows that increment or decrease the values (long click for.e.g to make start go past end, once you end the long click, only one validator is checked, while the other error remains even though it shouldn't). Any ideas how this  could be solved?

Comment: @ghoulfolk sure, just change the `keyup` event to a `change` event, [as shown here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ssmsus?file=app/app.component.html). Your issue is about change detection, not about the solution itself : you have to bind the correct events in order for your application to follow what you want.

Comment: @ghoulfolk but then again, you're supposed to put that kind of validation at form level. Here, you are willingly implementing a bad design. If it doesn't work, try following the best practices, and use the form-level validators !

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for the tips, I tried to put the (change) = "updateForm()" onto the parent mat-form-field, and I also tried to put (onSelectionChange)="updateForm()" onto the mat-options, but I still have the same problem. If start is for eg 100 and end is 99, both should show the error msg, but when I update start to be 98, only the error of start goes away and the error message remains for the end

Comment: @ghoulfolk then please make a question with a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I was planning on making a question about this, but then decided to go another way. I ended up dynamically changing the available selections on the "end" based on what the user selected on the "start" mat-select. That way I don't need to worry about the end being smaller than the start, and if the user then modifies the start to be bigger than the already set end, the end value is nulled, so the user has to select a new value to it from a list of values that are all bigger than the newly selected start.