# Why Angular 4 FormGroup custom validator not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

Trying to add custom validator `formValidator()` on a form group. Depending on some condition I am setting the errors `{invalidData: true}`. But when the condition is false setting errors to null. The control2 itself has required validator. If I set errors to null, it will also clear the required validator.

Refer the below code,

```
createReactiveForm(data: any) {
    const formGroup = new FormGroup({
        'control1': new FormControl(data.value1),
        'control2': new FormControl(data.value2, [Validators.required])
    }, this.formValidator());
}

formValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
        const control1 = group.controls['control1'];
        const control2 = group.controls['control2'];
        if (control1.value === 'ABC' && control2.value !== 'ABC') {
            control2.setErrors({ invalidData: true });
        } else {
            control2.setErrors(null);
        }
        return;
    };
}
```

What is the solution for this? Or am I doing anything wrong in the custom validator? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Validation functions aren't supposed to set errors on controls. They're supposed to return validation error objects.

```
formValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
        // use the abstraction provided by the framework
        const control1 = group.get('control1');
        const control2 = group.get('control2');
        // return the correct value depending on your condition
        return control1.value === 'ABC' && control2.value !== 'ABC' ? 
          { invalidData: true } : null;
    };
}
```

Comment: But i want to set the errors on control2. What is the solution? If I return the error object then how can I use that object to set the errors on control2?

Comment: I've already answer [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49896656/angular-4-validator-to-check-2-controls-at-the-same-time/49897087#49897087) a while ago. But the cleanest solution is indeed to keep the validator at group level, and use the condidition `*ngIf="form.hasError(...)"` instead of `*ngIf="form.get(...).hasError(...)"`

Comment: No, only one, that is at group level, and you make your conditions on the group instead of the control. Just like I just said ...